# The difference between FIT and FITTING

Tags: meaning

> 1 He is fit to do it.
>
> 2 He is fitting to do it.
>
> 3 The water is fit for drinking.
>
> 4 The water is fitting for drinking.

I can't pin point why it feels that 2 and 4 are wrong. If I think rationally, they must make sense. Are they wrong and why?

Comment: They absolutely are wrong. Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: "2 - He is fitting to do it" is fine if you mean he is a fitting choice (of ours), not that he is capable.

Comment: @YosefBaskin that wording sounds weird, you would not say he is fitting to do it, you'd say he is a fitting choice, or it is fitting to choose him.

Comment: @YosefBaskin humbly suggest you delete your comment (it's totally wrong, and totally wrong comments cause a staggering amount of confusion on this site). There are already a number of superb full answers in place.

Comment: FYI #1 is also totally wrong, @user1425

Comment: @user1425  When checking a dictionary didn't help, why not say which dictionaries you tried, and how or why they didn't help?

Comment: @YosefBaskin   I think you're mistaken.

'He is fitting…' will never work in English.

'He is fitted…' will work and seems to me to be what you meant.

'He is a fit or fitting choice…' would work and was that what you meant?

'It is fitting for him to do it' would be fine and was that what you meant?

Comment: Is this wrong "She was well fitting for the role of tragic heroine."?

Answer (score 8):

Don't be confused by the fact that the word 'fit' can also be a verb - as adjectives, '*fit*' and '*fitting*' are completely different words with different uses.

- 'Fit' means *able*, or *suitable or capable for a particular purpose or task*.
- 'Fitting' means *appropriate*, usually in terms of looks or behaviour, and this is not the right word for your example.

'Appropriateness' means suitability *in the context*, meaning something fitting/appropriate in one context may not be in another. 'Fit' is not usually contextual (unless you qualify it by saying *fit for purpose*); for example, a person who is physically fit doesn't become unfit in different settings.

**Examples:**

- If a source of water was declared "fit" to drink, it is *safe* and *suitable* to drink. That would be universally true - the water would be unsafe in any context or setting.
- We would say that a piece of music was "fitting" if it was *appropriate* to the setting. Most people would consider "*Disco Inferno*" to be inappropriate at a cremation as grieving relatives would not want to hear the chorus of *burn baby burn* as the coffin goes into the incinerator; yet the same song would be wholly appropriate at a disco party. *Context* makes it fitting.

Comment: So it means The water is appropriate for drinking, why is it wrong?

Comment: @user1425 It's wrong because 'appropriate' means *suitable or proper in the circumstances*. For example, "*Burn Baby Burn*" might be an appropriate song to play at a wedding party, not so much at a cremation. It's about *context*. Water is either safe to drink or not, that's why we would use "fit" or "suitable".

Comment: I can't be bothered, I wish someone would explain  fit to do it WRONG ready to do it CORRECT fit for a job CORRECT

Comment: @Astralbee Check if you mean safe or unsafe: "the water would be unsafe in any context."

Comment: @Fattie There is absolutely nothing at all wrong with ‘fit to do it’. It is perfectly normal, commonplace, idiomatic and correct. See for example the first highlighted collocation under [OLD _fit_, def. 1 and 2](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fit_2). You are 100% incorrect.

Comment: @user1425 [Judy Jones' answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/349443/42900) gives a great example of using _fitting_ together with _water_, and it is indeed dependent on a specific context: "Water is not fitting as an alternative to communion wine"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I'll have to think about that, thanks ..

Comment: FATTIE this is correct "... all the news that is fit to print." hence 1 is also correct.

Comment: @Fattie   What are you saying… come to that, why are you saying anything?

About what can you not be bothered?

What could 'explain fit to do it WRONG ready to do it CORRECT fit for a job CORRECT' mean? What could it mean in English or any other language, ever?

Comment: lol sorry @RobbieGoodwin !  it was csv with no commas :)

Comment: @user1425 news is plural, and "that is" is different in a way I don't understand from "he is". Also note that it's idiomatic "All the news that's fit to print"

Comment: @Fattie 'News' is **not** plural. It's just a word that ends in an 's'. That's why we use it with the definite article (ie *the news*) because it is one, non-countable noun. If it's plural, can you show me an example of someone referring to "a new"?

Comment: @Astralbee you're right of course.  But news is different from He in ways I don't understand. And  "All the news that's fit to print" is idiomatic, and idiom, like slang, doesn't count statistically in grammar "rules".

Comment: @Fattie  What does 'it was csv with no commas…' mean, please?

While you're  here, who ever said 'All the news that's fit to print' was idiomatic. If it was, how might that mean it didn't count in grammar?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "all the news that's fit to print" is undoubtedly a well-known phrase or reference, and hence an idiom. It's just an ***advertising slogan***, made-up in about 1900. Absolutely no different from "Just do it" or "It's Miller time" or "Bitte ein Bit"..  That's all it is, and all it will ever be. An advertising slogan. Slogans, and indeed idioms, are often slang-like and have little concern for "grammar".

Comment: @Fattie Sorry, that's not how idioms work… An idiom is not simply 'a well-known phrase or reference' but one which can't be understood by every-day rules of language. An idiom might include a recognised error - however slight. That 'All the news that's fit to print' is a phrase known in some quarters doesn't make it an idiom.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin PS you're absolutely right that that is the more correct usage of idiom. (Ironically I often rant about just that issue on here :) ) (idiomatic is different of course, *"using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker"*)  Back to the point, as I say in the usual bold italics, It's just an advertising slogan, made-up in about 1900. Absolutely no different from "Just do it" or "It's Miller time" or "Bitte ein Bit".. That's all it is, and all it will ever be. An advertising slogan. Slogans .. are often slang-like and have little concern for grammar

Comment: @Fattie   Thanks and how could that help?

Comment: My point is that "He is fit to do it." is (also) wrong; IMO the only reason it "sounds right" is - at best - the advertising slogan mentioned propagates that pattern. But, you know, it's a slim call. The whole QA annoys me because it presents four (garbage) sentences and then asks a (somewhat unrelated, anyway) obscure question.

Answer (score 6):

The use of fitting as an adjective is described in [this dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fitting#:%7E:text=fitting%20Word%20family%20%28noun%29%20fit%20fitting%20fitness%20fitter,fitting%20fit%20%E2%89%A0%20unfit%20%28verb%29%20fit%20%28adverb%29%20fittingly).

> fitting. *adjective*, *formal*
> right for a particular situation or occasion. SYN: appropriate
>
> - I thought the memorial was a fitting tribute to the president.
> - a fitting end to what was a memorable trip
>
> it is only fitting (that)
>
> - It is only fitting that Simon should propose the first toast tonight.

It seems unlikely that one would use fitting to say water is, or is not, appropriate, but this form is not impossible.

One could say, "Water is not fitting as an alternative to communion wine."

More likely one would say "This water is not fit to drink." Implying it is unpleasant or dangerous to drink .

Comment: You basically hit the main points.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this stack exchange 

Answer (score 4):

There are two reasons that 2 and 4 feel wrong. One is that "fitting" really means "appropriate *in a cultural sense*". A typical use might be:

> Her speech was a fitting tribute to her father.

The other reason is that "fitting" is a word that is just somewhat restricted in its natural use. It is relatively rare to see it used as a predicative adjective when not applied to the dummy subject "it". So

> It is fitting to drink Champagne at a celebration.

is very normal, but

> Champagne is fitting for celebrations.

sounds a little weird to my ear. Not ungrammatical, but not a phrasing you'd see often. On the other hand,

> Champagne is a fitting beverage for celebrations.

is natural. The difference is that, before, "fitting" is *predicative* - it is part of the predicate of the sentence, directly applying to the subject. But, in the last example, "fitting" modifies "beverage", and it seems natural.

Comment: ' "fitting" really means "appropriate in a cultural sense" ' that is it it is culturally appropriate, not physically appropriate. "it is not fitting to drink beer for breakfast", stick some negative examples in about drink to prove it isn't about the use of the drink but where or when you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

Only one of those examples works: 3 'The water is fit for drinking…' and there,'The water is fit to drink' would be more usual.

4 'The water is fitting for drinking' could never work. 'It is/could be fitting to drink the water' has a wholly different meaning.

1 'He is fit to do it…' should rather be, 'He is fit for it…'

Rather differently, 2 'He is fitting to do it…' should be, 'He is fitted to do it…' or, very differently, 'It is/could be fitting for him to do it…'

Comment: I disagree - 1 & 3 are fine; 2 is close / slightly unusual, only #4 is completely wrong.

Comment: If this is about 'fit' v 'fitting' then no. Looking again, I withdraw 1 'He is fit to do it…' should rather be, 'He is fit for it…' and suggest instead 1 'He is fit to do it' is quite different: 'He is physically capable of doing it'; ie, he isn't drunk, injured or ill.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin , nope 1 is fine, consider it an answer to a question "is he strong enough to climb this hill?"

Comment: @Wendy   Nope… Please read the Question again, then my Answer, then my response to MikeB then please show how your 'is he strong enough…' differs from my 'He is physically capable of doing it'; ie, he isn't drunk, injured or ill.

I say again, 'fit' as in the gym is wholly different from anything to do with the difference between 'fit' v 'fitting' as in suitability.

Does that not work for you?

Comment: At the risk of repeating a campaign plea, I think Down-votes should be allowed only when Down-voters explain. 

I couldn't care less who Downed me here, but as in all such cases, why should the 'defendant' not be allowed to know the nature of the 'charge'?

Comment: the only half-decent answer here

Comment: @Fattie  Does that refer to my Answer, or what, please?